# Seagate GoFlex NAS + Horrible Speed = Bad Experience

Tags: performance, nas, file-transfer

I am having issues with transfer speeds from my desktop PC to my NAS. I have my NAS hooked up to a Gigabit Gateway as well as my Desktop with Cat 5e. I see up to 4.0 MB/Second Transfer Rates, the normal is about 2.5 MB/Seconds.

There is 3 Partitions on my NAS, Public, Private, Backup. When I transfer from Private to Public I see the speeds above. If its under the same partition almost instant. I was wondering if the speeds I am seeing is in due to my Computer or the NAS. I was looking into building my own Media Server in due to these horrible speeds. Is their anything I can do in the mean time to speed this up?

```
Motherboard = M3970AM-HP (Angelica)
Processor = AMD FX 6100
Ram = 10GB PC3-10600 MB/sec
Hard Drive (1) = 1.5TB SATA 3.0GB 5400RPM
Hard Drive (2) = 120GB SATA SSD
NAS = Seagate 3TB Go Flex Home
Connection (1) = 1000 Base T
Connection (2) = Wireless N
```

Comment: What is a Gigabit Gateway ?

Comment: (Router + Modem) w Gigabit Ports